# HTML5 slide menu form right to left

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I am developing my first HTML5 page for mobile and desktop and I need to implement slide menu button! When you first click this menu button it will open menu which covers 50% of my screen and menu contain something similar to "log in bar"(some inputs and some text; like top right corener of FB), and after you click button menu, it will be hidden!
I have implemented some solutions but I'am not satisfied with them! 
One variant of  my menu is to do everything right but it is visible to user all the time! Animation works fine but when I want menu to be hidden, it becomes visible right of screen.

Other possible solutions :  picture and buttons go under the menu! When it opens, it "push" pictures and buttons below.

P.S i tried to add image but it seems that I don't have more than 10 reputation! Also, I didn't watch tutorials for jQuery so if any solution is theer in jQuery, please suggets me..

Comment: http://i1001.photobucket.com/albums/af133/Brutalika/stackover_question_zpsb7b3d07c.png

Comment: Provide what you've done please